# Change affilation in printed publication

Tags: affiliation

I am coauthor of publication (in Journal of archaeological science) and i want to change my Affiliation,  but publication is already printed (2014)...  Is it possible to change affilation after printing?

Comment: Do you propose that the publisher withdraw all the printed copies from the libraries and replace the page with you affiliation with a corrected one? This is not unfeasible, for example in Stalinist Russia libraries were occasionally ordered to replace certain pages in printed books for political reasons. But who will bear the costs?

Answer (score 11):

> Is it possible to change affiliation after printing?

No, at this point it's almost certainly too late.  If the affiliation was correct at the time, then there's no problem at all; it's understood that affiliations change over time and old publications are not updated.  If there was a minor error or oversight, then there's still probably nothing you can do about it now.  You could ask the editor whether it's possible to issue an erratum, but it would have to be a remarkably serious error to justify that.  (For example, an erratum could be justified if there's an error in the affiliation that creates genuine ambiguity as to who the author is, say if the publisher accidentally confused you with someone else with a similar name and listed their affiliation instead of yours.)