Should I add my old or new institute as affiliation?
If I did research while I was affiliated with institute X (collecting data from the patient's data of that institute) and now I left this for another one, which institute I should include when publishing?

I deleted the second question, as only one question per post is site policy. Concerning adding affiliation, see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/161866/change-of-affiliation-after-acceptance-of-a-paper

also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78160/change-affilation-in-printed-publication/78162#78162

For the first question, you should always mention your current affiliation. It would be good for many, including, administrative reasons. It does not harm if you mention in your paper that you did your research or collect data somewhere else.
For the second question, it is not possible to make any modifications once it is published and available online. Recently, some publications have started shown some relaxations, so you better approach the editors if there is any possibility.
